# Jquery Delay After Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a web app...

i got a kind of game, my idea is when the user completes each level appears a dialog box with some information, it is fine.

Now my issue is i want to show this message 5 seconds after the user clicks on the finish button.

thats my code:

```
$('#option-main-menu').click(function(){
        target.append('\
            <div id="confirm">\
                <h1>Are You Sure Want to Exist?</h1>\
                <a href="#" id="dialog-confirm">Yes</a><a href="#" id="dialog-cancel">No</a>\
            </div>\
        ');
    });
```

also i tryed with `append().Delay(10000)` but does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like the message, "Are You Sure Want to Exist?"

Comment: @Tim, this is the Dr. Kevorkian game. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` with a delay of 5000 ms.

```js
$("button").click(
    function() {
        console.log("clicked...waiting...");

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                alert("Called after delay.");
            },
            5000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Just out of curiosity, why would you want to wait 5 seconds before prompting the user in response to an action? That's a long time; long enough for them to have clicked on a bunch of other things (if nothing else).

Answer (score 13):

You could try using `setTimeout()`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/CCnZY/).

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // do stuff here, in your case, append text
}, 5000);
```

The `5000` can be replaced with any value of time that determines the length of the delay in milliseconds.

Comment: Wrong. `delay()` only affects that animation queue.

Comment: @SLaks: Good point--I didn't realize that. I've edited my answer and added an example.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
$("button").click(
function() {
    console.log("clicked...waiting...");

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            alert("Called after delay.");
        },
        5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't delay an append.  You can only delay animations.  You could use `setTimeout` or show the element initially hidden and then fade it in:

```
$('<div id="confirm" style="display:none"> ...')
    .appendTo(target)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('#option-main-menu').click(function(){
    setTimeout(
        function(){
         target.append('\
            <div id="confirm">\
                <h1>Are You Sure Want to Exist?</h1>\
                <a href="#" id="dialog-confirm">Yes</a><a href="#" id="dialog-cancel">No</a>\
            </div>\
        ');
       }
        , 5000);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").click(
    function() {
        console.log("clicked...waiting...");

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                alert("Called after delay.");
            },
            5000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. Explain this so it helps future visitors.

Comment: This is pretty clear for a "code only" answer, but I agree with @SterlingArcher; it needs at least some commentary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourThing.click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){do your thing here},5000)
})
```

Comment: You need to pass a function, not call it:

yourFunction, instead of yourFunction()

Comment: @pascalbetz yes, that was bad pseudocode on my part. Fixed. Thanks!