# Adding delay and showing a message when input button clicked

Tags: php, javascript

I have an input button that submits content from the front end for review in the back end. The problem is it doesn't show a confirmation message - it's not setup as a form otherwise this would be easy (I cannot change it to a form either).

The input button has a unique ID - I would like to add a small delay of say 5 seconds when the button is clicked AND it to show a message saying 'thanks the content has been submitted for review'. Is this possible with Javascript or PHP?

The code I have for the button is:

```
<input type="button" class="button-primary" id="wdqs-post" value="Post">
```

Comment: Yes, please provide existing code.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes this is possible with JS

Comment: please refer to this post
[Jquery Delay After Click][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752541/jquery-delay-after-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/rKjbq/)

Example Test1:

**HTML Test1**:

```
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="showAlert();"></input>
```

**JAVASCRIPT Test1**:

```
function showAlert() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert('thanks the content has been submitted for review');
    },5000);   // 5 seconds
}
```

Example handling the onclick with javascript and showing the alert before delay: [Test2](http://jsfiddle.net/rKjbq/5)

**JAVASCRIPT Test2**:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function(){showAlert()};

function showAlert() {
    alert('thanks the content has been submitted for review');

    setTimeout(function() {
        // DO OTHER STUFF
    },5000);   // 5 secon
}
```

Example showing the alert in a DIV: [Test3](http://jsfiddle.net/rKjbq/12/)

**HTML Test3**:

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Test"></input>

<div id="alert" style="display: none;">
    thanks the content has been submitted for review.
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT Test3**:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function(){showAlert()};

function showAlert() {
    document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(function() {
        // DO OTHER STUFF
    },5000);   // 5 secon
}
```

**CSS Test3** (very simple):

```
#alert {
     border: 1px solid;
     height: 20px;
     width: 400px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 150px;
     top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply - something like this is what I wan't but ideally not an alert, instead for it to show a hidden div or something. Also I cannot add a onclick function or anything to the button so it will need to be grabbed via ID if possible?

Comment: I just tested this, is it possible to have the alert show straight away rather than after the delay?

Comment: @RICKYDAWN I eddited the script handling the onclick with JS and showing the script before the delay. Give me a sec and I will show you how to show a hidden div.

Comment: Perfect thanks for the help with this - a quick question on the section 'DO OTHER STUFF' what goes here, because I am not sure exactly where it goes or what the button does (apart from submit content to the admin) is there a line I can add there that basically says 'do whatever the button was going to do' :/

Comment: @RICKYDAWN you can remove that setTimeout function. I left it there if you want to do something else after showing the alert, and 5 seconds after your click the accept button in the alert message.

Comment: I tried setting this up, but no luck - please can you see here: https://fapps.wrdadmin.co.uk/pruprotect/informationform/

It's the post button (you'll need to login with FB)

Comment: I don't have a FB account :(

Comment: Ahh ok - I'm getting this in the console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null - I placed the script in the header, and I tried it in the footer.

Comment: Maqjav - it works now, you are a star. I cannot thank you enough!!

Comment: The page needs to be rendered. Add it in an onload function: `<body onload="load()">`. JS: `function load() {document.getElementById("myButton").onclick=function(){showAlert()};}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['rbutton']) == null)
{   echo "thanks";
    $time = 2; 
    $url = "http://localhost/method/index.php";  
    Header("Refresh: $time; url=$url");  
    exit();
}
```

you can use these kind of php code, it shows message and after 2 second delay, re-direct any page you want... (this if is optional you can check another thing or server response)