# Wait before url is opened after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

When the button is clicked I need the page to wait for .8s to open the link in the same window, due to a site animation.

This time out code below only works if the href target is `_blank` and not if the target is the default `_self` - the link then becomes `undefined`.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  setTimeout(function(url) {
    window.location = url;
  }, 800, linkUrl);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><button id="button">Click</button></a>
```

**How can I fix my code so that it will wait for .8s before the new link is open in the same window when the button is clicked?**

Comment: you mean that you want to wait that the new page will load the content before to focus the new opened window?

Comment: Looks like you're missing another zero in the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trigger the anchor href if you click on the button. Just remove the `a` tag and set the `window.location`.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = "https://www.w3schools.com";
  }, 800);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

U should use `location.href = "url.com"` or `window.open("url.com")` instead of in the tag.

check those posts for deeper understanding
[Jquery Delay After Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752541/jquery-delay-after-click)
[Open URL in same window and in same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab)

```js
$("button").click(
    function() {
        console.log("clicked...waiting...");

        setTimeout(
            function() {
                location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752541/jquery-delay-after-click";
            },
            800);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```